# Google BigQuery with javascript - how to get query exe time and how much data (in size) processed by query

Tags: javascript, api, methods, google-bigquery, execution

I am new to BigQuery and need more functions in BiogQuery + Javascript so i can get total execution time and how much GB of data processed by that query.

How can i know total exe time and processed data size in javascript api.

Eg. Query complete (1.6s elapsed, 35.7 GB processed)

the above example result from javascript api.

The total processed bytes i can get from response. But query exeution time from where i will get this. I dont want to run timer (to calculate time) before and after query exe.

Also need a intel on how to see executed query history from JavaScript api.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine how long a job took, you can compare [`statistics.creationTime`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.creationTime), [`statistics.startTime`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.startTime), and [`statistics.endTime`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.endTime), depending on your needs.  These can be accessed from the [`jobs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) or [`jobs.get`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) API.  These responses will also contain the bytes processed by a query in the [`statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed) field.

To retrieve a history of jobs (including queries, and any other load, copy, or extract jobs you may have run) you can call the [`jobs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) API.

Specifically in JS, if you have a query response containing a `jobReference`, you can run something like the following to retrieve the full job details using the `jobs.get` method and log them to the console.  The logged response should contain the fields linked above.

```
var projectId = response['jobReference']['projectId'];
var jobId = response['jobReference']['jobId'];
var path = 'https://clients6.google.com/bigquery/v2/projects/' + projectId + '/jobs/' + jobId;
var request = {'path': path, 'method': 'GET'};
gapi.client.request(request).execute(function(response) { console.log(response) });
```

Comment: As there is not starttime and endtime not even creationTime in the response from the query. I can totalBytesProcessed. But no execution time. Please tell me from where i will get this exact time.

Comment: I assume you are using the `jobs.query` and/or `jobs.getQueryResults` API methods.  There should be a `jobReference` in the response which can be used to look up the full job details using a `jobs.get` API call.

Comment: i have been using gapi.client.bigquery.jobs.query

Comment: do u know how to use statistics.query and all the query exe stats details. Please give me code link also so i can understand the code also.

thanks in advance !

Comment: but jobReference contains only follwoing,

jobReference: ObjectjobId: "job_39EBAtjVzTSpeLUMNPs3tPjQ6NU"projectId: "alpine-XXXX-9XX3"__proto__: Object

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example of how use that `jobReference` and the `jobs.get` API to retrieve the full job details, which include the statistics you're looking for.